# Startup in GRUB with dual boot Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have installed a dual boot of Ubuntu 18.10 and Windows 10.

Now when I start up my PC it goes directly to Windows 10. I have to click esc to abort the automatic startup and go to the GRUB options.

I want my PC to start up in GRUB so I can choose which OS to boot.

I have tested this process:

I have tried running this command in Ubuntu:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

and rebooted, but it didn't work. The terminal says that if it didn't work I should post this URL:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VKW6QVyZWD/

What should I do

First 15 lines of `/etc/default/grub`

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
```

When I run the command, `grep -A3 -B1 timeout /boot/grub/grub.cfg` I get:

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
/boot/grub/grub.cfg:  set timeout=30
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-else
/boot/grub/grub.cfg:  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
/boot/grub/grub.cfg:    set timeout_style=menu
/boot/grub/grub.cfg:    set timeout=10
/boot/grub/grub.cfg:  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-  # unavailable.
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-  else
/boot/grub/grub.cfg:    set timeout=10
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-  fi
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-fi
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
--
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-}
/boot/grub/grub.cfg:set timeout_style=menu
/boot/grub/grub.cfg:if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
/boot/grub/grub.cfg:  set timeout=10
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-fi
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
/boot/grub/grub.cfg-
grep: –: No existe el archivo o el directorio
grep: Paul: No existe el archivo o el directorio
grep: Benson: No existe el archivo o el directorio
grep: 2: No existe el archivo o el directorio
grep: hours: No existe el archivo o el directorio
grep: ago: No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

Thanks!

Comment: Report in lines 599 thru 630 show your issue. Grub only boots working Windows, or Windows that is not hibernated. And Windows fast start up sets the hibernation flag. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: I have already changed the fast startup mode.

Comment: And it doesn't work

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe how the system works now and what do you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want GRUB menu to be shown at startup, then comment out

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

to be

```
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

to `/etc/default/grub`, then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: It's already set at 10 seconds, according to *grub.cfg* in pastebin.

Comment: Why not simply do it?

Comment: Yeah, is says this:
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

So I asume its already set at 10 seconds

Comment: Can you see the difference between `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10`?

Comment: I tried this, and didn't worked. Should I delete the GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 line?

Comment: I changed the answer. Now a newer version of grub is used, not like I have.

Comment: It didn't work. I deleted the command GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10 maybe that wasn¿t correct.

Comment: Also, when I start my pc it says, theres a problem that must be repair and doesn't continue the startup process.

Comment: GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 should stay if you are trying to get to the Grub menu. Will you please post up the file `/etc/default/grub` (the first 15 lines will be enough) and state what it is you are trying to do, as it's not exactly that clear (to me).

Comment: I jusy posted the first 15 lines as part of the question. @PaulBenson

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` after that?

Comment: Grub file looks correct now. As suggested, after you alter anything in `/etc/default/grub` and saved it  you must run `sudo update-grub` for those changes to the file to take place. Let us know the result.

Comment: I runned sudo update-grub, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: OK. Run the following command and post up output: `grep -A3 -B1 timeout /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: There I posted the output.

Answer (score 0):

There's one more solution for this:

Boot into Windows and download easybcd application and then run it as an administrator.

Make an Ubuntu entry in easybcd and then add that entry with Windows in **edit boot menu**.

Uncheck **skip boot menu** option.

Then test it whether it works, and if not then repair boot files through it making sure that Ubuntu entry is still alongside the Windows entry.

For detailed steps see the section of [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/-iSAyiicyQY) from 9:16 minutes to 10:00.